# CheckBox not Working from inside a Repeater in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is what I wrote inside the Repeater

```
<td style="text-align: center; width: 60px">
   <asp:CheckBox ID="DeleteCheckBox" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id")%>' AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="DeleteCheckBox_Click" />
td>
```

and this is the C#

```
protected void DeleteLinkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LinkButton BtnId = (LinkButton)(sender);
            string ButtonId = BtnId.CommandArgument;
            long Active = 1;
            if (ButtonId !=string.Empty) 
            {
                if (DeleteCheckBox.Checked==true)
                {
                    objdalTransactionEntry.RentSettingsIsActiveUpdate(Convert.ToInt64(ButtonId), Active);
                }
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

The Problem is that it is not being able to find the ID of the checkbox `DeleteCheckBox` in C# code

Comment: Confusing actions of users here! Is the user to simply click, click click away on several check boxes and THEN click a delete selected button that is outside of the grid? Or is the use to check the box, and then hit a delete button on the same row? (rather confusing - why not just have a delete button then????). So the mixing up of multiple check boxes, and that of having multiple delete buttons has confused the HECK out of the posters here! If the user is to JUST check several check boxes, then the check box does NOT need any postback event code (the trick of settnig "ID" + command is good!

Answer (score 0):

Based on you code, I have the following comments:

1. Change you function name, it's confusing. It should either be `DeleteCheckBox_Changed` or it should not be used for the `OnCheckedChanged` event
2. Your sender is not a `LinkButton` it is the checkbox itself. So you can access the checkbox control with `CheckBox checkBoxThatChanged = (CheckBox)(sender)`
3. `DeleteCheckBox` does not really exist. You have multiple `DeleteCheckBox`s due to your repeater, so you won't be able to access it this way.
4. If you are indeed using a `LinkButton`, and you want to find a checkbox, then you should add a value to the link button, indicating the row of the table it refers to and iterate through all the checkbox controls until you find your target one.